# Flutter & Go Router: Unexpected behavior when browser back button is pressed

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I'm using go_router version 12.1.1 and I have the 3 nested routes like `/b/c`.

Assume I go (using `context.go()`) from `/` to `/b`, then from `/b` to `/b/c`, then I click back browser button, then I go to `/b/c` again (repeat several times).

**Current behavior**

I have to click browser back button several times to get to the home page again (it goes through all the pages I have visited in the reverse order: `/b`, `/b/c`, `/b`, `/b/c`, `/b`, `'/'`). All these pages were really visited in the browser, so from the browser's point of view it is correct...

**Expected behavior**

...but from the user's or app's point of view I don't think it is correct. If you use the navigation bar's back button it works in a different way (like I think it should work). Also, if I just call `context.pop()` it works the same way too, so I can click 2 times and get to the home page no matter how many times I open and close the nested routes before.

As for me, it is very strange that 2 back buttons provide different results and as for me it is not useful in web browser.

**Question**

Is there a way to make browser back button work as the Android's back button or navigation bar's one? (It works exactly as I need when go router is not in use.)

**Code for testing**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Go Router',
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}

class PageAScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageAScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<PageAScreen> createState() => _PageAScreenState();
}

class _PageAScreenState extends State<PageAScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('A'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text('A'),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Go to B'),
              onPressed: () => context.go('/b'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageBScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageBScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<PageBScreen> createState() => _PageBScreenState();
}

class _PageBScreenState extends State<PageBScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('B'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text('B'),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Pop to A'),
              onPressed: () => context.pop(),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Go to C'),
              onPressed: () => context.go('/b/c'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageCScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageCScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<PageCScreen> createState() => _PageCScreenState();
}

class _PageCScreenState extends State<PageCScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('C'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text('C'),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Pop to B'),
              onPressed: () => context.pop(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => const PageAScreen(),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: 'b',
          builder: (context, state) => const PageBScreen(),
          routes: [
            GoRoute(path: 'c', builder: (context, state) => const PageCScreen()),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```